# Extjs Grid Filter list cascading

Tags: extjs, filter, grid, extjs6.2

I am using sencha extjs 6.2 gpl version.

I have a grid with three columns having list filter. Once I apply the list filter on column 1, I want column 2 filter list to be updated with all list items relevant to column 1 selection. But in my case though the list is filtered correctly on column 1 but in second column filter list all distinct values from whole store are present while I want only filtered. here are my columns having filter.

> ```
>   { text: 'District', dataIndex: 'district', flex: 1, filter: { type: 'list'}},
>   { text: 'Tehsil', dataIndex: 'tehsil', flex: 1, filter: { type: 'list'}},
>   { text: 'Union Council', dataIndex: 'uc', flex: 1, filter: { type: 'list'}},
> ```

I want to cascade the filter lists based on selection. Any help how could I do that.

Comment: Any code what you did till now?

Comment: Nothing just made the grid with column as mentioned above, the grid data is loading well. Now just want list cascade in the above columns.

Comment: Anyone who knows how to cascade filters in multiple column as we do in MS Excel.